How to run a detached server in github actions for windows os
I want to run Vault server in my ci. For ubuntu everything work properly. I run
vault server -dev -dev-root-token-id="root" -address="http://127.0.0.1:8200" & disown

and then i can install other dependencies and run tests.
How can i implement the same for windows cmd?
I tried:
start /b vault server -dev -dev-root-token-id="root" -address="http://127.0.0.1:8200"

cmd /c "START /b vault server -dev -dev-root-token-id='root' -address='http://127.0.0.1:8200'"

cmd start vault server -dev -dev-root-token-id="root" -address="http://127.0.0.1:8200"

and many other options but sometimes it just loops the current server process, sometimes just breaks it.
